# Is it necessarily true that if a polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_n$ ($n$ is prime) then it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have played around with a couple examples and I've consistently seen a pattern where the polynomials that are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$. Can anyone challenge this statement? How about in the reals - that is if a polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_n$  does the same hold in $\mathbb{R}$? I have not taken a formal course in abstract algebra, but I am curious as an outsider what the reasoning is like from a mathematician's point of view.

Comment: In the name of the Lord, if it is prime then write it with a $p$! :-)

Comment: In the name of the Lord, if it is $\frac{\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}$ the finite ring you mean, do not write it as ${\mathbb Z}_n$ !

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, that one is not as established, really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I am interpreting $\mathbb Z_n$ as $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, is this the case here?

This is indeed true if the leading coefficient of the polynomial is equal to $1$ and the coefficients are in $\mathbb Z$: if $p$ is reducible over $\mathbb Q$, then $p=qr$, and the leading coefficients of $q$ and $r$ is $1$, and so $q$ and $r$ are nonconstant in $\mathbb Z_n$, so $p$ is reducible in $\mathbb Z_n$.

If the leading coefficient is not $1$, then this is not always true: $2x^2+3x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_2$, but not irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, since it is equal to $(2x+1)(x+1)$.

Finally, $x^2-2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_3$, but not in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: $x^2-2$ is not irreducible in ${\mathbb Z}_3$, is it ? Perhaps you meant $x^2-3$

Comment: If it were, then it would have a root in $\mathbb Z_3$, and it does not. On the other hand, $x^2-3=x^2$ in $\mathbb Z_3$, so it is reducible.

Comment: I see you are interpreting ${\mathbb Z}_n$ as $\frac{\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}$, I was interpreting it as the $p$-adic ring

Comment: That's a good point, I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: @detnvvp: is your proof correct? when writing $p = qr$, the equality holds in $\mathbb Q[X]$. You should make sure that $q,r$ are actually in $\mathbb Z_n[X]$, is it right?

Comment: I edited it, I'm considering that the coefficients are in $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a neat theorem, called the localization principle, which may be what you're looking for:

Suppose that $f= a_0 + a_1 x + ... + a_n x^n$ and that $a_0, a_1, ... , a_n$ are relatively prime. Suppose that $p$ is a prime which does not divide $a_n$. If $\bar{f}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z_p}$, then $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$.